# Cant link master blade to bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I am having trouble with linking master blade file with bootstrap files as css and js. I cant format the class jumbotron to see if its linked correctly now its just showing as text. This is the blade file and the bootstrap files:

[image]

Code in default.blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>NIH</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/hvertime', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Hver Time') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/hvertredjetime', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Hver Tredje Time') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/gjoremal', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Gjøremål') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/dagvakt', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Dagvakt') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/kveldsvakt', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Kveldsvakt') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/kontrollcm', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Kontroll CM') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/sok', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Søk') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/diagram', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Diagrammer') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </td>

            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/rapport', 'method' => 'GET')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Rapport') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}


                {{ HTML::linkRoute('kveldsvakt', 'kveldsvakt') }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <p style="color: green;">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
    @endif
    <div id="test"> @yield('content')


         <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->


      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
        <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->



        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>




    </div>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest loading the jquery and boosttrap.js files directly after opening the body , instead of at the bottom of the page. Also, open the chrome inspector and see if it produces any errors. If it can't find a file you are including it will state that in an error message .

Comment: where are your js and css folder located in project. put them in public folder and blade files in views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it this way

```
<title>NIH</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
<!-- Add custom CSS here -->
{{ HTML::style('css/main.css')}}

<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```

Comment: The same thing for the `js` scripts
`{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }}`
`{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}`.

But this time is `HTML::script` instead of `HTML::style`.

Answer (score 1):

Well your view files should be in view folder under path :

```
/app/views/
```

Read [this](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading) link for laravel file structure

Anyway You can do it in this way. If your css and js is in public folder:

```
 //js
  <script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
         'or'
   <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
 //css
 <script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
```

Comment: This is so much better: `<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: And `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">`

Comment: In fact even better is `HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css');` and `HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js')`

Comment: why not CDN? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">`